# How do I calculate the dimensions of windows from a picture of a building using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am a beginner in OpenCV and I am trying to get dimensions of windows from a picture of a building that I have. I was able to have contours appearing on the picture and thus was able to get the outline of the windows on the building. However, I am lost as to how I should proceed on estimating the window dimensions.

Additionally, after reading stuff on this link: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/28/measuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/, I realized that I would need to have a object whose dimensions is known so that I can use it to then find the dimensions of other objects. As I don't have that sort of an object, is there a way I can tackle this problem?

Comment: If you have no ground truth in your image to go off of, no---you cannot. In the same way that you wouldn't be able to tell the size of a window from a photo, either.

Comment: If you have two offsetting views (i.e. from different locations) of the same image and have camera models for each, it is possible to intersect rays (if not collinear) to the same feature and knowing the image points compute the intersection in 3D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size of object in image is relative. It refers to the fact that the more distant an object, the smaller its image will be on the retina. Therefore, if there are two identical objects, the one that is farther away will be the one that has a smaller image on the retina. For example, if we assume that the two street lamps in the photograph below are the same size, then the street lamps with a smaller image on the retina must be farther away from the viewer. As the image of the closest street lamp is the largest in the picture then we assume that it is the closest to the viewer. Note that the street lamps in the background does not look abnormal in any way. Despite creating a smaller image on the retina, the street lamps do not look oddly small. The normal size of the more distant street lamps is due to a mechanism called size constancy.

So, you do need to have an object whose dimensions is known so that you can use it to find the dimensions of other objects.

[image]